# How to use a a string of one class in another class?

Tags: c#

I have a class in `test.cs` in which I have a string value `string user="testuser"`. I want to use the test.cs's `user` value in another class. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declare the string public:

```
public string user = "testuser";
```

Then you can access it from another class via

```
Test.user
```

However, depending on what exactly you want, you should perhaps make the field read-only:

```
public readonly string user = "testuser";
```

Or use a property, bound to a backing field:

```
public string User
{
    get { return this.user; }
}
```

In fact, properties are the canonical way of making information accessible from the outside except for very few, very special cases. Public fields are generally not recommended.

As [Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11529/ant) mentioned in a comment, there is also the option of making it a constant (assuming it is, in fact, a constant value):

```
public const string user = "testuser";
```

Comment: Then why recommend it if they aren't recommended?

Comment: Because it's the quickest way to make it work and requires the least amount of understanding. I could write a multi-page essay on why fields are bad and properties should be used but the OP probably just needs to get a job done or it's a one-off thing where it doesn't even matter. Someone asking such a question probably does *not* currently design a framework or library millions of customers will use.

Comment: Don't forget the const option too! :)

Comment: without going on too long, surely the idea to to further someone knowledge with a "best practice" approach. Better to teach them well at the start in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Make a public property.

```
Public string TestUser
{
 get { return testUser;}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should make a property of user and expose this to any other class that want to read or write it's value.

```
class MyClass
{
    private static  string user;

    public static string User
    {
        get { return user; }
        set { user = value; }
    }

}

class MyOtherClass
{
    public string  GetUserFromMyClass()
    {
        return MyClass.User;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class AClass
{
   // declarations
   private string _user = "testUser";

   // properties
   public string User { get { return this._user;} set { this._user = value; } }
}
```

then call your class property, e.g.

```
AClass myClass = new AClass();
string sYak = myClass.User;
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the earlier answers, making "user" into a Property is the ideal technique of accomplishing this. However, if you want to expose it directly anyhow, you should use static to avoid having to instantiate an object of that class. In addition, if you don't want the demo class to manipulate the value of user, you should declare is readonly as well, like below

```
public static readonly user="text user";
```